# Difference between view.php and _view.php in yii

Tags: php, yii

What is difference between view.php and _view.php in Yii?

Where I should use from _view or view in Yii?

By render()  or renderPartial() I can render both? hasn't problem in performance or anything?

Comment: Its just two file names ...

Comment: There's no functional difference, only a semantical one - an underscore prefix is an unofficial indicator "this is a private/helper file, don't use it outside its intended context". Many other coding conventions agree with this use of the underscore prefix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are simply filenames, but by default view.php is used with a `render()` and _view.php is used with a `renderPartial()` (in the default Yii web application).

So if we stick to this convention, any view rendered by `render()` will be a "normal" file name, and anything rendered with a `renderPartial()` will have a prefixing _underscore.

Here is the difference between render and renderPartial (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379817/yii-difference-between-rendering-functions)):

**`render()`** is commonly used to render a view that corresponds to what a user sees as a "page" in your application. It first renders the view you have specified and then renders the layout for the current controller action (if applicable), placing the result of the first render into the layout. It then performs output processing (which at this time means automatically inserting any necessary `<script>` tags and updating dynamic content) and finally outputs the result.

**`renderPartial()`** is commonly used to render a "piece" of a page. The main difference from `render()` is that this method does *not* place the results of the render in a layout. By default it also does not perform output processing, but you can override this behavior using the `$processOutput` parameter.