# Yii render variable not view file

Tags: php, yii, renderpartial

question is: `Does Yii have any method(s) to render variable with code in it?`
Default:
`$this->render('site/index');` where `site/index` is path to view file.
What I need to do is:
`$content = '<div><?php echo "do something here"; ?></div>';`
`$this->render($content);`
Output should be layout + parsed content

I tried to use `$this->renderText($content);` but this methods returns empty string.
I'm using Smarty extension to render view files, then `$this->renderText($content);` returns not parsed string: `{assign ..}`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some rendering Functions in Yii you could use to get there, but not with a variable. It would be better to use renderFile(). If you want to pass data to this file use

```
$this->renderFile("renderfile.php",array("var1"=>"xyz","var2"=>"abc");
```

[More render funtions described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379817/yii-difference-between-rendering-functions)

Comment: Yeah.. but I need exactly variable not file